# Numpy index into columns independently

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

Let's say I have an array like

```
arr = np.arange(27).reshape(9,3)
```

And I have a list of indices like so:

```
idx = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0],
                [1, 7, 1],
                [5, 6, 7]])
```

where `idx.shape[1] == arr.shape[1]`. What I want to return is this:

```
out = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
                [ 3,  1,  2],
                [ 3, 22,  5],
                [15, 19, 23]])
```

That is, an array where for some `(i, j)`, `out[i,j] == arr[idx[i,j], j]`.

Comment: Use `np.take_along_axis` : `np.take_along_axis(arr,idx,axis=0)`.

Comment: Or `arr[idx,[0,1,2]]`